# Preserve cifs file permissions in samba share

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba, cifs

I have run into a weird samba/cifs problem with file permissions.  Im running ubuntu and have a cifs share configured in my /etc/fstab

```
//server.addr.com/folder/myFolder /home/Tommy/myCode cifs credentials=/root/.cifs,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

The share works fine, but the file permissions are being changed from the original.  For example when I do an 'ls -lsha' from a locally downloaded copy of the repository I see:

```
Tommy@dev:~/reposit/thing1$ ls -lsha
total 40K
4.0K drwx------  2 Tommy Tommy 4.0K Jun 21 12:23 .
4.0K drwx------ 19 Tommy Tommy 4.0K Jun 21 12:23 ..
8.0K -rw-------  1 Tommy Tommy 7.6K Jun 21 12:23 Thing1.cpp
12K -rw-------  1 Tommy Tommy 8.8K Jun 21 12:23 Thing1.h
4.0K -rwx------  1 Tommy Tommy 2.0K Jun 21 12:23 Makefile
4.0K -rw-------  1 Tommy Tommy  976 Jun 21 12:23 Support1.cpp
4.0K -rw-------  1 Tommy Tommy 3.1K Jun 21 12:23 Support1.h
```

However when I do the same thing from the share I see:

```
Tommy@dev:~/myCode/reposit/thing1$ ls -lsha
total 5.0M
   0 drwxr-xr-x 2 Tommy TomGrp    0 Jun 21 12:35 .
   0 drwxr-xr-x 2 Tommy TomGrp    0 Jun 21 11:47 ..
1.0M -rwxr-xr-x 1 Tommy TomGrp 7.6K Jun 21 12:35 Thing1.cpp
1.0M -rwxr-xr-x 1 Tommy TomGrp 8.8K Jun 21 12:35 Thing1.h
1.0M -rwxr-xr-x 1 Tommy TomGrp 2.0K Jun 19 09:08 Makefile
1.0M -rwxr-xr-x 1 Tommy TomGrp  976 Jun 21 12:35 Support1.cpp
1.0M -rwxr-xr-x 1 Tommy TomGrp 3.1K Jun 21 12:35 Support1.h
```

Two things stand out: 1 the file sizes are different, and 2 the permissions have been changed.   I'm mostly concerned about the permissions aspect (I have diffed the files and they are identical).

I did try changing my smb.conf to have

```
map archive = no
```

[as recommended here.](https://superuser.com/questions/427850/preserve-permissions-on-samba-shared-files-when-overwriting) To no avail.